How can I determine f0 using a spectrogram?
Especially with vowels, I am analyzing speech using Praat but I am not sure how I can find the value for f0.

Using a spectrogram
If you want to find f0 on a spectrogram, you're going to need really good frequency resolution, which means sacrificing time resolution. In other words, you want your spectrogram to look horribly smeared horizontally, until you can pick out thin individual bands vertically.
Then, f0 is the frequency of the lowest band (i.e. the lowest harmonic). But, I don't really recommend doing it this way.
Using Praat
If you're using Praat, there's no need to analyze the spectrum by hand! In the spectrogram window, go to Pitch > Show Pitch, and now it'll be drawn as a blue line over the spectrogram.
Note that this blue line uses a different scale than the spectrogram itself—look at the blue numbers on the right side. Since the fundamental frequency is always at the very bottom of the spectrogram, putting them on the same scale would compress one or the other into uselessness.
You can also select a region of the spectrogram and do Pitch > Get Pitch to get a more precise number.
